# Did the Greeks build temples for all of the children of Cronus?

Tags: greek

I know that the Ancient Greeks built temples for a lot of the children of Cronus, such as the [Temple of Zeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Zeus,_Olympia) and the [Temple of Hera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Hera,_Olympia). Were temples built for all of the children of Cronus, or were they only built for the major ones? If some were left out, is there any indication of why?

Comment: Did Cronus have children other than Zeus, Hera, Poseidon, Hades, Hestia, Demeter, and Chiron?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the traditional geneaology of the Greek Gods, Cronus had six children with Rhea: Hestia, Zeus, Hera, Poseidon, Hades and Demeter. All children were part of at least one major variation of the Twelve Olympians and - with the exception of Hestia - had temples honouring them.

Hestia was Cronus firstborn and her sanctuary was the hearth of the [Prytaneion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prytaneum), the political and religious center of the community. Also, Hestia was thought of as being present in every offering fire in all temples and received first offering in sacrifices. Thus, she didn't need temples of her own.

Of course there may have been temples honouring Hestia that we simply don't know about. After all, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: There appears to be reference to a sanctuary of Hestia in Hermione, from Pausanias "Description of Greece" (http://www.theoi.com/Text/Pausanias2C.html , 2.35.1), if that's useful.

Comment: @femtoRgon Good find. Every hearth was essentialy a sanctuary to Hestia, and there probably were several shrines and offering fire altars dedicated to her all around Greece. But I'm not aware of any actual temples.

Comment: Where is or was there a temple to Hades?

Comment: @BrianDonovan I'm only aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromanteion_of_Acheron